# HTML 5 microdata product name is a image

Tags: image, product, microdata

This is the code:

```
<article>
<img itemprop="name" src="img/product_name.png">
<p>Product text</p>
</article>
```

Normally I could do this:

```
<h3 itemprop="name">Product name here</h3>
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: May I ask *why* you use an image instead of providing the name as text?

Answer (score 3):

Remember, microdata is about letting machines understand your page. Hiding text in an image is the opposite and will make any microdata useless.
But you can add the correct metadata in the page without it showing to the visitor.

I would solve it like this:

```
<article itemscope>
  <img itemprop="image" alt="textual name" src="img/product_name.png" />
  <meta itemprop="name" content="textual name" />
  <p>Product text</p>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

So like Michaël Hompus said, you can us `meta`, you can refer to this link below for more explanation.

[here, an example on htmlgoodies](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/other/html5-microdata-why-you-should-use-it.html#fbid=TTUd9-SbezM)

Here my example :

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <img itemprop="image" src="img/product_name.png">
   <meta itemprop="name" content="name of product here" />
   <p itemprop="description">Product text</p>
</article>
```

and you can add more details : [see here](http://schema.org/Product)